# How to view the files on mnt\sdcard on PC and how to set default download and save location

Tags: internal-storage

The directory mnt\sdcard is the location where all the downloads and the received files are saved, however this file cannot be located on the PC if connected using USB Cable. Moreover, it seems that this file is on the Phone's Internal Memory and not in the Memory card

Comment: Could you please specify the device used? On all of mine, /mnt/sdcard *is* on the sdcard (basically, it is the *root* of the sdcard). Second: If you have two questions, you should better ask them separately (you can still cross-reference if needed).

Comment: I'm using Sony Xperia Sola (MT27i) Android 2.3.7. While using File maneger Applications like Astro, I am able to see a directory called mnt\sdcard in which all the downloaded files are present. From the same application, Im also able to see a directory mnt\ext_card which contains the files that I have copied on to the memory card before mounting it in the Phone using a card reader.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that, like on the [Atrix](http://androidforums.com/other-androids/353366-rooting-samsung-galaxy-player-50-a.html#post2819395), `/mnt/sdcard` is your internal storage, while `/mnt/ext_card` is your real sdcard. You can verify this if you check their seizes: You know the size of your sdcard, so you should be able to point that out. The internal will probably have a size which is not a multiple of 8 (most likely, it will be 6 GB or the like).

If you are unsure how to check this, you could e.g. use [SanDisk Memory Zone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sandisk.mz)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS21C.jpg)</sup> or, even better, [Storage Analyser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelokment.storageanalyser)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdJnF.jpg)</sup>, which should make it easy to point out:

[image: SanDisk Memory Zone] [image: Storage Analyzer]